# Sumar columnas con DataTables jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

¿Qué cambios hay que hacer en este código para que funcione con este formato de número 2.222,33? Ahora es valido para 2222.33

[Ejemplo de suma con DataTables](https://codepen.io/RedJokingInn/pen/PbrqWa)

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podrias usar algo como esto:

```js
var formatterUSA = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-USA', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});
var nuevo_formatoUSA = formatterUSA.format(2500);
alert(nuevo_formatoUSA);
```

Para mayor informacion sobre el formato: [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat)
aplicado a datatables:

[Formato numero Datatables](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBxXgY)

Espero te sirva de guia..!!